# why is a While loop not working in C# XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, while-loop

I am trying to make Keybinds/Hotkeys for a game i am making

Problem: Movement works once, and then ends code.

I tried making A permanent while loop so that it wont leave the code ever,
after i added the while loop, it doesn't even register the key being pressed!
i know the problem is with the while loop because i put it into a comment and the code works like it did
before i coded in the while loop.
(i am using XAML too.)
(playerBody is a canvas)

code:

```
using System;

namespace GameWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           Thickness speed = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 100);
            bool d = false;
            while (d == false)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.W)
                {
                    PlayerBody.Margin = speed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set `d` to true - how do you expect it ever to end?

Comment: The loop never ends -> the UI thread is blocked -> no UI action can be performed -> application gets "stuck"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people have already pointed out, an endless loop is not a good idea.

I also don't think that your code is executed only once. In fact, it should run in there again and again as long as a key is pressed. However, you always assign the same offset (`Thickness`). The value thus always remains at 100 because it is not added up.

```cs
Thickness speed = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 100);
// ...
PlayerBody.Margin = speed;
```

Try something like this:

```cs
int speed = 100;
// ...
PlayerBody.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, PlayerBody.Margin.Bottom + speed);
```